# How do I avoid inheritance and still make it look as though I'm calling one class?

Tags: php, inheritance, design-patterns, composition, php-5.5

I'm interested in how the following can be properly done without using inheritance:

I'd want to make a call in my app like this:

```
// I don't want to do this:
// $temp = new Sedan;
// $myCar = new Car($temp);
// $myCar->paint();

// nor this:
// $myCar = new Car(new Sedan);
// $myCar->paint();

// Instead I want this:
$myCar = new Sedan;   
$myCar->paint();
```

The paint method is actually part of class Car:

```
class Car {
    private $carToPaintOn;  // <-- Instance of Sedan would be stored here      

    public function __construct(CarInterface $car){
        $this->carToPaintOn = $car;
    }

    public function paint(){
        // paint some car
    }
}
```

What would class `Sedan` (or `Coupe` or `Convertable` or etc...) look like without using inheritance?
The class code must use industry standard design patterns and follow guidelines for clean and testable code. Also please avoid duplicating the `paint` method by additionally adding it to Sedan.

**EDIT**: In hindsight I should have named the class "Car" to something else and given it an interface called "Paintable" to better get the point across.

Comment: Your professor doesn't want us answering your homework.

Comment: Look at my profile, I'm not in college. :-p

Comment: But rather I'm trying to settle a discussion I've been having with some other folks (if you must know) hah!

Comment: Not possible. You can't instantiate a `Sedan` object and have it return a `Car` object. To get close, you could combine the Factory and Delegate Patterns. But even that won't meet all of your requirements, e.g. indirect instantiation and automatic dependency injection.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary https://gist.github.com/prograhammer/83299972ff87b17cd219#file-interiordecorator-php

Comment: Please don't do this at home, kids.

Comment: The reason kids is simply "because I said so"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be inheritance, as a Sedan IS A car, but a Sedan does not HAVE A car, but if you really wanted to avoid it...

```
class Sedan implements CarInterface {
    private $car;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->car = new Car($this);
    }
    function __call($method_name, $args) {
        if (!method_exists($this, $method_name)) {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this->car, $method_name), $args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know, I just think cars are easy to think about and couldn't think of another simple (all my examples head towards complexity) subject.

Comment: Whoa! Ok this is seriously close to my solution I was thinking, but I had put that constructor and __call both into a trait

Comment: So what I'm thinking that, if I wanted to call `Sedan` in such a way, just include the trait. Otherwise I could use the typical Decorator call approach.? It's like a reverse of Decorator. I call it Interior Decorator.

Comment: Would this be acceptable practice? (ie. composition over inheritance and so on)

Comment: There is a name for this: *Delegation*.

Comment: Here's a simple gist I wrote up recently: https://gist.github.com/prograhammer/83299972ff87b17cd219

Comment: Dave, one more thing...would it be acceptable to do `$this->car = new Car($this)` in that constructor you have in your answer, so that Car get's the instance of Sedan it needs to work on?

Comment: And of course Car would accept the interface for Sedan, not specifically Sedan.

Comment: I mean, acceptable is a relative term.  Do I love the idea?  No.  I don't think a car should worry about the details of a sedan.  But yeah, if you pass in an interface, then I start to like it for certain situations.

Comment: Yeah, because that takes care of `// $myCar = new Car($temp);` as I mention at the top of my question that I didn't want to write out all the time.

Comment: Ok Dave, I added a constructor to my Car class (see my question now). If you update your answer to match, then we are good to go!

Comment: In hindsight I probably should have said "Paintable" instead of "Car" for that class.

Comment: Awesome, thanks man! You came to the exact same solution I did in a discussion I had (except I offered a trait to hold this repeated constructor and __call)

Comment: BTW, this is a good way to be able to type-hint `Sedan` in Laravel 5's controller methods to be automatically validated [ie. FormRequests ValidatesWhenResolved](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#controller-validation)

Answer (score 1):

This example is a perfect example for inheritance. The following code will do exactly what you said you want to do. There's no need for traits or injecting something here. [DEMO](http://3v4l.org/hXMfX)

```
<?php

class Car {
    public function paint () {
        echo " ________   \n";
        echo "/        \__\n";
        echo "|___________\\\n";
        echo "  O      O\n";
    }
}

class Sedan extends Car {

}

$sedan = new Sedan;
$sedan->paint();
```

Comment: The point of the example is to show how it could be properly done without using inheritance. I've heard senior devs who say they haven't used inheritance in years!

Comment: @DavidGraham: It could be done, but "properly" doesn't fit in here.